# stddef.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

> features.h

HISTORY: I was having problem with header files then I tried changing compiler path and include in `c_cpp_properties.json` (now the squiggle under header file is gone)

```c
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"hello world";
}
```

PROBLEMS:

```
[{
"resource": "/c:/mingw/include/wctype.h",
"owner": "cpptools",
"severity": 8,
"message": "stddef.h: No such file or directory",
"source": "gcc",
"startLineNumber": 87,
"startColumn": 20,
"endLineNumber": 87,
"endColumn": 20
}]
```

OS: windows 10
Editor: VS code
Language: c++
Compiler: MinGW

`c_cpp_properties.json` file:

```json
}
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:\\MinGW\\include",
                "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: The c_cpp_properties.json file does not effect compilation, only the squiggles. The tasks.json file is where you should be looking to fix compilation problems.

Comment: First question: Can you compile the hello world using the commandline? If the compiler install is somehow broken, no VS.code configuration is going to make it work.

Comment: Last time I installed Linux from scratch it took me just under two hours. I got a modern C++ compiler, fully configured, and all development tools, installed as part of my Linux distribution. How long has it taken, so far, to download and manually install an editor on MS-Windows, then attempt to separately download and install gcc, a ported compiler, and then attempt to glue everything together, with nothing working in the end?

Comment: If you don't want to follow Sam's advice to reinstall your computer with Linux, another option is to install the Visual Studio 2022, which comes with everything preconfigured, including a Hello World program that is guaranteed to work right out of the box. Or you could try the [17 page config guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) for VS Code.

Comment: VSCode is a monstrosity. No doubt experienced users can get something from it, but for some reason newbies are drawn to it. and it seems most of them end up here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik As far as I know MS compiler doesn't run at all under Linux. At least Windows users have the possibility to run gcc (and they can do it in a way much simpler than via VSCode).

Comment: If the goal is to learn C++, @john, the fact that the MS compiler doesn't run on Linux is not an obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure VSCode will not understand a path written like this: `/c:/mingw/include/wctype.h`. Remove the first slash so the path starts with `c:`.

Also MinGW is very old (so is GCC 6.3.0), consider moving to MinGW-w64, which is much more up to date and supports both Windows 32-bit and 64-bit and more recent versions of Windows.

There is a standalone build of latest MinGW-w64 + GCC available on https://winlibs.com/ which requires no installation, just unzip and change the paths in `c_cpp_properties.json`.